# How to extract middle of string in java using regex

Tags: java

Hi can anyone please tell how can I get 23,45 from string [{"Tpid":"23, 45"}] Using regex in java?

Comment: Use the GSON library or another parser.

Comment: Must it be done using Regex?  It looks very simple to simply use String indexOf and substring to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to make a method to address this specific input or inputs of this type?

Comment: Actually it is just an example I might have large data (around 1k)means [{"Tpid":"23, 45,67...."}] . In this case I don't want to use substring

Comment: Is there a blank in `23, 45`? Then getting `23,45` via regexp will be a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
.*:"([^"]*)"}\]
```

Be aware that if this string matches, you need to get the match group to extract the value in braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String msg = "[{\"Tpid\":\"23, 45\"}]";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*:\"([^\"]*)\"}\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(msg);
    if (matcher.matches()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```